# Numpy: Find maximum value and corresponding location along one axis in 3D array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am looking for an efficient way to find the maximum value and corresponding index along the first axis of a 3D array using Numpy.

**Context:** 
I am working with data stored in a 3D array `z.shape() = (t, x, y)` and have taken a Fourier transform along the `t` axis using

```
spectrum = np.fft.fft(z, axis=0)
spectrum.shape(f, x, y)
```

Here, `f` is the frequency space, having the same size as `t`.

I need to construct an array `peak_vals.shape() = (x, y)` which holds the highest value of the transformed data for each x- and y-coordinate. Moreover, I need to store the frequency corresponding to each peak: `peak_freqs.shape() = (x, y)`

I already have a function that computes the frequencies corresponding to the Fourier transform:

```
def freq_arr(t):
    """Determine the frequency space that a DFT of vector t would have"""
    samp_freq = 1/(t[1]-t[0])
    return np.arange(len(t)) * samp_freq / len(t)
```

To find the peak along the `f` axis, I came up with:

```
peak_vals = np.amax(spectrum, axis=0)
```

How can I find the frequency corresponding to these peaks? I would like to construct a function

```
def peaks(freqs, spectrum):
    peak_vals = np.amax(spectrum, axis=0)
    # do something
    return peak_vals, peak_freqs
```

I want to avoid `for`-loops since I will be working with large arrays.

Comment: `np.argmax` returns the index where `np.amax` occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def peaks(freqs, spectrum):
    peak_vals = np.amax(spectrum, axis=0)

    # get the indices with the max value
    peak_idx = np.argmax(spectrum, axis=0)

    # now use the indices to get the corresponding frequencies
    # peak_freqs is now 2d even though freqs is 1d
    peak_freqs = freqs[peak_idx]

    return peak_vals, peak_freqs
```

Comment: `freqs` is a 1D-array, since it is just a transformed time axis., so in can't be unpacked into `f, x, y`. I also don't fully understand the `flatten()` part.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I must have overread that the freqs is just a 1D-array. Then the problem becomes even simpler, without using the flatten part.

Comment: Indeed seems to do the trick. Thank you. I wasn't aware of this manner of passing indices.